# How to relate doctor and patient entities in spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-design, data-modeling

I'm very new to spring boot. I am creating a health centre management system where I have 2 entities `Doctor` & `Patient`.

*There are few rules that are followed*

- There can many doctors in a centre
- There can be multiple patients too
- A doctor can see multiple patients a day
- But a patient can only have an appoinment with a single doctor at a time.

This is my `Doctor` entity:

```
package com.sb.projects.java.spring.medical_api.entities;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Doctors {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String degree;
    private String specialization;
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Patients> patient = new HashSet<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDegree() {
        return degree;
    }

    public void setDegree(String degree) {
        this.degree = degree;
    }

    public String getSpecialization() {
        return specialization;
    }

    public void setSpecialization(String specialization) {
        this.specialization = specialization;
    }


    public Set<Patients> getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }

    public void setPatient(Set<Patients> patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }
}
```

This is my `Patient` entity:

```
package com.sb.projects.java.spring.medical_api.entities;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Patients {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String contact_no;
    @ManyToOne
    private Doctors doctor;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getContact_no() {
        return contact_no;
    }

    public void setContact_no(String contact_no) {
        this.contact_no = contact_no;
    }

    public Doctors getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctors doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }
}
```

**Here are the few problems that I'm facing**

- I'm not sure about the type of relationship that I'm setting between the `Doctor` and `Patient` Enity is correct
- If the relationship is correct then I'm not sure about the `setPatient` setter function in `Doctor` entity, that my implentation of the setter function is the right way of doing the thing or not
- If the all the above points are okay then what will be a perfect mockup json object which will be in a http POST request body to test the Doctor Entity

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a Doctor without taking any patient into account something like this:

```
POST http://locahost:8080/v1/doctors

{
    "name": "doctorName",
    "email": "somemail@xyz.com",
    "degree": "xyz",
    "specialization": "a"
}
```

When you want to add a patient to your doctor then you would just call another endpoint to create a visit between your doctor and your patient

```
POST http://localhost:8080/visits/{patientId}

body...
{
"doctorId": idOfDoctor,
}
```

With this you would attack the patient's db repository to create a relation between your patient and your doctor.
It sounds extrange to me to relate directly the doctor with the patients, i would do a middle relation like "VISITS" with the day of visit and the hour...

Comment: If I pass only the id of a doctor entity to the patient does it autometically map to each other

Comment: can you elaborate on what do you mean by middle relation ? A seperate table ?

Comment: Yes you would have a new table called "VISITS"
With FK of doctor and patient the doctor would have N visits and the patient would have just 1 (as you described on your question - although from my point of view a patient should be able to have more than 1) . If you need more info i can extend the answer with little example

Comment: Yes please if you can extend the answer with a little example that will be really great. It will be really helpful in my learning